# cannot find symbol class EditText, where is this error coming from?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Whenever I run this, I get an error, please help me debugging this short code. Previously before adding menu everything was running well. Can I get a solution to make it running?
What do I need to add or remove? Stuck a little . Every answer will be appreciated.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

//import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idbtn);
    }

    public void btnClick (View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"You touched me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this,"You like it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    Button btn2;
    EditText numTxt;
    String sNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.item1:

                Toast.makeText(this,"settings selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.item2:
                Toast.makeText(this,"change appearance",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            case R.id.item3:
                Toast.makeText(this,"rate us in store",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't `import` it.

Comment: Post your logcat

Comment: Add `import android.widget.EditText;` below of all `import` statements. Or go to on word where error occurs it may be in red color font and press `alt + Enter` it will import lib itself.

Comment: Check out this shortcut, it will format your code:
Win(Ctrl + Alt + L)
Linux(Ctrl + Shift + Alt + L)
Mac(Option + Command + L)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `EditText` class.
Add

> import android.widget.EditText;

Go to on word where error occurs it may be in red color font and press **`alt + Enter`** it will import corresponding class itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to import the `Edittext` class.

Just to import **`EditText`**

`import android.widget.EditText;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the EditText class, so it's known, using the following line at the beginning of your .java file :

import android.widget.EditText;

Answer (score 0):

Try importing [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) class

```
import android.widget.EditText;
```